# Bash check if all files in a folder are writable by www-data

Tags: linux, bash

I have a logs folder and sometimes some log files are owned by `root`, but I need them to be owned by `www-data`.

I'm writing a script that will check if they are all owned by `www-data` = writable to that user.

```
#!/bin/bash
rootfiles=$(ls -lA /tmp/logs/ | grep root | sed -e 's/\s*$//')
if [[ ! -z "$rootfiles" ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

This works fine, but only if I assume there'll be no file that contains the word `root` in it's name, and that all that's not root is `www-data`.

How could I make it more robust?

Comment: Use `find` for this job and take a look at `man find`.

Comment: Well I don't know how, that's why I ask. I can use `find` to find by name and type, but that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to find out:

```
find /tmp/logs -not -user www-data
```

But, to to change the owner of all the files, you can use recursive `chown`:

```
chown -R /tmp/logs/* www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-user` option in `find` for this:

```
find /tmp/logs -not -user www-data
```

To change ownership:

```
find /tmp/logs -not -user www-data -exec chown www-data {} +
```

Comment: Well I'm running it as www-data, called from php, to show a warning if the files aren't writable ∴ I can't change ownership; but thanks

Comment: Actually user `www-data` cannot change ownership of files that are NOT owned by that user. I think you will need use `sudo` or run this as `root`.

Comment: of course, I don't try to change the ownership at all, this is just for diagnostics